# Why can't I view source maps with Angular and Browserify?

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I am trying to step into the Browserify world.  I am using a [this](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter) tutorial as a starter.  The source maps work fine.  As soon as I require in `angular` the source maps disappear.  Here is my `browserify` task.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify({
            entries: ['./src/javascript/app.coffee'],
            extensions: ['.coffee', '.hbs']
        })
        .bundle({debug: true})
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

I am passing in the `debug: true` flag.  Is it even possible to make source maps with `angular`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have the debug flag in the wrong location, try moving it into the call to `browserify()`.

```
gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify({
            entries: ['./src/javascript/app.coffee'],
            extensions: ['.coffee', '.hbs'],
            debug: true //moved to here
        })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```